# Caching the last emitted value from an observable

Tags: system.reactive

In many cases I find myself needing to access the most recently emitted value from an observable. The way I've done this is by subscribing to the observable and caching values as they appear. See below for example. However I see there are a bunch of methods like Observable.MostRecent, Observable.Latest, Replay(1), etc. which seem like they might accomplish what I'm looking for, but I can't figure out how to use them. Is there a better approach than the method I'm using below?

```
public class WordPrinterWithCache
{
    string _lastWord = string.Empty;

    public WordPrinterWithCache(IObservable<string> words)
    {
        words.Subscribe(w => _lastWord = w);
    }

    public void PrintMostRecent() => Console.WriteLine(_lastWord);
}
```

Comment: Did you end up using some of my suggestions or did you implement your own method?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid needing to do this at all and the most I structure my code around observables and less around mutable variables, the easier to do it. If I want the most recent, I use CombineLatest or WithLatestFrom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two methods I would consider when implementing this behavior.

```
var bs = new BehaviorSubject<long>(0); //initial value
source.Subscribe(bs.OnNext);
Console.WriteLine(bs.Value);
```

With `BehaviorSubject` you can access the latest value through a property.

```
var ls = source.TakeLast(1);
bs.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

With `TakeLast` you must subscribe to access latest value (though only one value is emitted before disposal).

Comment: BehaviorSubject doesn't address the problem of having an IObservable and wanting to get the latest value. If I had a BehaviorSubject to start with I'd just call the .Value method. Helpful to remember that TakeLast - and probably those other similar sounding methods - only really DO something when you subscribe.